# MySQL suddenly running very very slowly

Tags: mysql, database-tuning

I run a PHP/MySQL website on a fairly large server with 16GB RAM and 3 vCPUs.

Everything was flying along until this morning when I noticed MySQL down.

I tried to restart MySQL and first got the `too many connections` error.

I didn't know why it was showing this, So killed MySQL processes and restarted the database after changing `my.cnf` to 500 Max connections.

However, MySQL is still very slow even after running `optimize`.

Any hints about what is happening, or how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Have you noticed a significant increase in traffic to your website?